# Insert trigger for foreign key string to int

Tags: mysql, triggers

**EDIT**
Just to add a bit of clarity to what I'm trying to achieve with this design. Data will be inserted into tbl1 which will be a user entry.
My intention is to store the different possible values for foo in tbl2. Such that there is a unique ID attached to each possible foo value.

**END EDIT**

I have two tables with syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `foo` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY(`foo`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `value` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER `trigger1`//
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger1` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl1` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT(10);
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl2` WHERE `value`= NEW.foo) = 0 THEN INSERT INTO `tbl2` (`value`) VALUES (NEW.foo); SET x=last_insert_id();\
ELSE SET x=(SELECT `id` FROM `tbl2` WHERE `value`= NEW.foo);
END IF;

SET NEW.foo=x;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that MySQL is rejecting a varchar value for foo and thus an insert as follows:
    INSERT INTO `tbl1` (foo) VALUES ('bar');
Will insert a record into tbl2 with value 0.

Are there any other approaches to this that can achieve the correct result (without changing foo to a varchar)?

Comment: What I was intending to do isn't quite supported by MySQL, so I've had to stick with a varchar field for this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because you're trying to insert 'bar' a string into the table field foo for tbl1 wich is of type int, and according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-invalid-data.html):

> If you try to store a string that doesn't start with a number into a
>   numeric column, MySQL Server stores 0.

So before the trigger gets executed the value 'bar' is converted to 0.

Comment: I've added further clarity in the original post to explain what I'm after. A workaround of making foo a varchar(100) is my only other way forward. That is unless there is a better way to do this.